# sorting complex php array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, cron

I have an array of cronjobs on my server, which I need to sort by the date they fire, the starting array is:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 00 08 24 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command 
[1] => 00 09 24 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command
[2] => 00 08 18 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command
[3] => 00 11 18 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command
)
```

I want this list represented in a table on my website, but sorted by month, day of month, hour, minute.

The desired output is:

```
Array(
[0] => 00 08 18 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command
[1] => 00 11 18 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command
[2] => 00 08 24 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command
[3] => 00 09 24 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command
```

Can anyone point me in the direction I need to go in order to achieve this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you might have to write a function to compare each row, then sort the array using that function with [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Comment: The array values are all strings, right?

Comment: Use `usort`, define your own sort rule.

Comment: Each entry in the array is a string, yes. In the case of usort - how would I go about defining a rule that can sort these strings by the 4th -> 3rd -> 2nd -> 1st set of numbers in the string?

Comment: A simple `strcmp` + `usort` should do it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What's complex in this array? It's a unidimensional array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
$a = array(
  '00 08 24 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command',
  '00 09 24 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command',
  '00 08 18 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command',
  '00 11 18 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command',
);

usort($a, function($f, $s) {
   $fx = implode('', array_reverse(preg_split('/\D+/', $f)));
   $sx = implode('', array_reverse(preg_split('/\D+/', $s)));
   return strcmp($fx, $sx);
});

var_dump($a);
/*
0 => string '00 08 18 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command' (length=48)
1 => string '00 11 18 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command' (length=48)
2 => string '00 08 24 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command' (length=48)
3 => string '00 09 24 10 * 2012 curl --user user:pass command' (length=48)
 */
```

What I've done here is basically extracting all the numeric parts from all the strings in question, then reversing them into a numeric string, then comparing these strings.

This can be modified in two ways: first, hardening the regex so it won't match numbers in command itself:

```
   $fx = implode('', array_reverse(
     preg_split('/(?<=\d{4}).+$|\D+/', $f)));
```

... and second, using a memoizing function:

```
function getSortCriteria($line) {
  static $criterias = array();
  if (! isset($criterias[$line])) {
    $numbers = preg_split('/\D+/', substr($line, 0, 18));
    $criterias[$line] = implode('', array_reverse($numbers));
  }
  return $criterias[$line];
}

usort($a, function($f, $s) { 
  return strcmp(getSortCriteria($f), getSortCriteria($s)); 
});

var_dump($a);
```

Here I removed the rest of the string with `substring`; it's more efficient, I think. Still, showing how this can be done with regex might be useful as well. ))

Comment: Actually, I want the lowest value at the top. These are all dates (in a very weird format) which I want sorted from earliest -> latest, also the first and second are minutes and hour, your sorting writes 11 earlier than 08 - which is slightly wrong, though very close to what I need.

Comment: That might make it simpler to explain, true enough.. Edited to show the desired output.

Comment: Updated my answer; as I said, it's just using `strcmp($f, $s)` instead of `strcmp($s, $f)` (`-strcmp($s, $f)` should do as well).

Comment: Well that was me being a fool, that went totally over my head with strcmp($f, $s). Sorry about that.. Thanks a ton for your help, it works perfectly now!